# CSS Search Box Expanding

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/LukzzXB/pen/yrMjxg

So i am coding a text box using CSS. If you see the link above you'll see that when i hover over the button the 'Type to search' works fine as it goes to the right.

Now i'm just trying to get the background of the button to go with the text box aswell.

So the goal here is to try get the box to expand right and only right.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js">
  </script>`enter code here`
  </head>
  <head>
    <title>Using CCS for the first time</title>
  </head>  
  <head>
  <style>
    h1 {

    color: orange;
    text-align: left;

    }

    </style>
    </head>
      <body>
    <h1>
      <span style="font-family:Arial">Hello and welcome to a search box</span>
    </h1>
      </body>  

<head>
<body>
<div class="search-box">

  <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
  <a class="search-btn" href="#">
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </a>
</div>  
</head>

    </body>
</html>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
   }

.search-box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #2f3640;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
   }

   .search-box:hover > .search-txt{

       width: 240px;
       padding: 0 6px;
   }

   .search-box:hover > .search-btn{
    background: white;

}

   .search-btn{
    float: left;
    color: red;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.4;   
   }

   .search-txt{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0px;
   }
```

Comment: Can you post a mockup image of your intended result?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eovbjW

You should only have one `HEAD` and one `BODY` tag on the page.

It was the `float` + `display:flex` that messed things up for you. I rarely use float myself nowadays, to be honest.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

    <title>Using CCS for the first time</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello and welcome to a search box</h1>

    <div class="search-box">
      <div class="fas fa-search"></div>

      <input class="search-txt" type="text" placeholder="Type to search" />
    </div>  

  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**
[edit] If you're not familiar with CSS variables, I used them here, in `.search-text` as a guideline of how to use them. In the `left` attribute in `.search-text`, I even used `calc()` to add two CSS variables together.

```
:root {
  --background-black: #2f3640;
  --background-red: red;

  --search-box-padding: 10px;
  --search-box-size: 40px;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: var(--background-red);
}

h1 {
  color: orange;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: var(--search-box-size);
  width: var(--search-box-size);
  background-color: var(--background-black);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: var(--search-box-padding);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-box > .fa-search {
  padding: var(--search-box-padding);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--background-red);
}

.search-box:hover > .fa-search {
  background: white;  
}

.search-txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--search-box-padding);
  left: calc(var(--search-box-size) + var(--search-box-padding));
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  height: var(--search-box-size);
  width: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

  background-color: var(--background-black);
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s width, 0.4s padding;
}

.search-box:hover > .search-txt{
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
}
```

Comment: this is is exactly what i'm looking for thank you. The only problem with it now is that the 'Type to search' appears to be lower than the actual button. I tried to self-fix this but i couldnt find the what sort of code this would be under. Just started CSS ;p

Comment: I'm sorry. I only tried it in Firefox. I updated my answer in the post to work Chrome, and hopefully all the other browsers. I tried it now in Mac Safari as well, and if it works in that browser, it will work everywhere. :)

Comment: Cheers mate brilliant!